# custom trie container insert r-value semantics

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I have the following declarations for my insert member functions:

```
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(value_type const& pair);
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(value_type&& pair);
```

Once I implemented the move(&&) version it is the only one ever called. I am trying to pass the following unit test.

```
using mapped_t = std::string;
using vector_t = std::vector<mapped_t>;
using trie_t = trie<mapped_t>;
using key_t = trie_t::key_type;
using map_t = std::map<key_t, mapped_t>;

vector_t data{ "nine", "ten", "seven", "eight", "five", "six", "three", "four", "one", "two" };
map_t m;
trie_t t;
for (auto datum : data) {
    t.insert(trie_t::value_type(datum, datum));
    m.insert(map_t::value_type(datum, datum));
}

BOOST_CHECK(std::equal(t.begin(), t.end(), m.begin()));
BOOST_CHECK(t.size() == m.size());
```

But it is calling the && function not the const& one. Not sure why the const& is never called.

If I remove the && implementation the const& is called and I pass the unit test.

What are the side effects of using the following:

```
 if (currentNode->data == nullptr) {
    currentNode->data = new value_type(std::move(pair.first), std::move(pair.second));
    currentNode->incrementSize();
}
```

Comment: Because you're always passing an r-value? Why do you suppose the `const&` overload should be called?

Comment: I've got it working with just the && implementation now. Wondering what the side-effects may be from using std::move() in the code added above.